# Specify the Template for a From within a Django Crispy Form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I have a crispy form in which I want to render a separate form. I am able to render this second form just fine but need to style it. I'm trying to specify a template for this separate form (the FacilityForm). How can I do that? 
I show/hide this separate 'facility form' based on whether or not the user clicks "add a new facility".

My Crispy Form:

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    # Fields- many more fields that I haven't listed here
    sample = forms.CharField(
        label="Sample",
        max_length = 50,
        required = True,
    )

    data_type = forms.ChoiceField(
        label="Data Type",
        required = True,
    )

     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Fieldset(
                "Data Information",
                 Div(
                     Div('lab', css_class='col-xs-6'),
                     Div('sample', css_class='col-xs-6'),
                     css_class='row'
            ),

            Div(
                Div('facility', css_class='col-xs-6'),
                Div( HTML("<a href='#'>Add a new facility</a>"), css_class='col-xs-6 addfacility'),
                css_class='row',
            ),
            Div(
                HTML("'{{facility_form}}' <a href='#' id='cancelFacility'>cancel</a>"),
                css_class='new_facility',
            ),

        ),
```

The Separate form:

```
class FacilityForm(forms.Form):

    facility_name = forms.CharField(
        max_length=256,
        required=True,
    )

    address_line1 = forms.CharField(
        max_length=256,
        required=True,
    )

    country = forms.CharField(
        max_length=50, 
        required=True,
    )

    state_province = forms.CharField(
        max_length=100, 
        required=False,
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is perhaps redundan but I just used many Divs within an outer Div whose `css_class` I set to `new_facility`:

```
            Div(
                Fieldset('Facility Information',
                    Div(
                        Div('facility_name', css_class='col-xs-4'),
                        Div('address_line1', css_class='col-xs-4'),
                        Div('address_line2', css_class='col-xs-4'),
                        css_class='row',
                    ),
                    Div(
                        Div('country', css_class='col-xs-3'),
                        Div('state_province', css_class='col-xs-3'),
                        Div('city', css_class='col-xs-3'),
                        Div('postal_code', css_class='col-xs-3'),
                        css_class='row',
                    ),
                ),
                Fieldset('Facility Contact Person',
                    Div(
                        Div('first_name', css_class='col-xs-4'),
                        Div('middle_initial', css_class='col-xs-4'),
                        Div('last_name', css_class='col-xs-4'),
                        css_class='row',
                    ),
                    Div(
                        Div('email', css_class='col-xs-12 col-sm-6'),
                        css_class='row',
                    ),
                ),

                HTML("<a href='#' class='btn btn-default pull-right' id='cancelFacility'>Cancel</a>"),


                css_class='new_facility',
        ),
```